# How to make a clickable vertical accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, click, accordion

I am making a website for my master's course, and I wanted to make a vertical clickable accordion mechanism. The ideia is to click in every  section and it expands with more information.
So far, I've just made it with the hover mechanism using CSS. How can I make it clickable and use JS? If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

```css
body {
  width  : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  margin : 0;
  }
ul,
li {
  margin     : 0;
  padding    : 0;
  list-style : none;
  }
ul {
  display  : flex;
  overflow : hidden;
  height   : 100vh;
  width    : 100vw;
  }
li {
  overflow-y         : scroll;
  overflow           : auto;
  -webkit-box-flex   : 1;
  -webkit-flex       : 1;
  -ms-flex           : 1;
  flex               : 1;
  width              : 8.3vw;
  height             : calc(100% - 1%);
  -webkit-transition : -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition : -webkit-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : -ms-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : flex 500ms ease-out;
  padding            : 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  -moz-box-shadow    : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  box-shadow         : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  }
li:hover {
  -webkit-box-flex : 30vw;
  -webkit-flex     : 30vw;
  -ms-flex         : 30vw;
  flex             : 30vw;
  }
.projects {
  width         : 30vw;
  height        : auto;
  margin-bottom : 5vh;
  }

/* ------- PARAGRAPH STYLES ------- */

a {
  text-decoration : none;
  color           : black;
  }
a:hover {
  opacity : 0.5;
  }
.maintitle {
  width          : 100%;
  font-size      : 30px;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  font-family    : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
.subtitle {
  width       : 150vw;
  font-size   : 20px;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
img {
  padding-top : 20px;
  width       : 25vh;
  height      : auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> MDC 22-23 </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <!-- MICRO-1-->
    <li ">
            <div class="projects ">
                <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                    <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                    <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                    <img src="gif5.gif "></div> 
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="projects "></div>
                <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                    <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                    <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                    <img src="gif5.gif "></div> 
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="projects "></div>
                <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                    <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                    <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                    <img src="gif5.gif "></div> 
                </a>
            </div>
          
         
        </li>

        <!-- PROJECT 2-->
       
        <li>
            <div class="projects ">
                <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                    <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                    <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                    <img src="gif5.gif "></div> 
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="projects "></div>
                <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                    <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                    <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                    <img src="gif5.gif "></div> 
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="projects "></div>
                <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                    <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                    <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                    <img src="gif5.gif "></div> 
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <!-- PROJECT 3 -->

        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
    </ul>

  
</body>
</html>
```

So far, I've just made it with the hover mechanism using CSS. How can I make it clickable and use JS? Also could i make every  with infinite auto scroll? If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a runnable code snippet, that allows us to see, and reproduce, your problem. I have *not* fixed any typos though, as we're not supposed to, in case that inadvertently fixes the problem and makes the question redundant (if fixing typos does fix the problem however, the question will be closed as "not reproducible, or a typo"). May I ask that *you* correct the typo (there's at least one stray `"` character in an opening `<li>` tag), I didn't check further.

Comment: there is many typo errors, like `<div class="projects "></div>` or `<img src="gif5.gif "></div>`. you need to check your code with a HTML validator.

Comment: or can you explain why there is 18 `<div ..>` and 28 `</div>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.  Basically I have just replaced your `li:hover` selector with `li.selected`.  Now it just uses some simple JS to add/remove that `selected` class when you click on an `<li>` tag.

NOTE: I dorrected quite a few syntax errors that commentors above have mentioned.  I also removed all of those `-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-ms-` prefixed items as those are largely no longer needed.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    unselectAll()
    listItems[i].classList.add("selected");
  }, false);
};

function unselectAll(){
  for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].classList.remove("selected");
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

li {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  width: 8.3vw;
  height: calc(100% - 1%);
  transition: flex 500ms ease-out;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
}

li.selected {
  flex: 30vw;
}

.projects {
  width: 30vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}


/* ------- PARAGRAPH STYLES ------- */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.maintitle {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.subtitle {
  width: 150vw;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 25vh;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <!-- MICRO-1-->
    <li>
        <div class="projects ">
            <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                <img src="gif5.gif ">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="projects ">
            <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                <img src="gif5.gif ">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="projects ">
            <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                <img src="gif5.gif ">
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- PROJECT 2-->

    <li>
        <div class="projects ">
            <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                <img src="gif5.gif ">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="projects ">
            <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                <img src="gif5.gif ">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="projects ">
            <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
                <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                <img src="gif5.gif ">
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- PROJECT 3 -->

    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is vague.
If you have to use a click to select a pane of your accordion, what happens to the hover on the others elements?

Here is an answer that combines the two
the hover has priority over the click, but the pane opened with a click remains open outside of any hovering of the set.

you just have to put as a selector:

```css
ul#vertical-accordion:not(:hover) li.selected,
li:hover {
   ...
```

Optionnaly you can add

```css
ul#vertical-accordion:hover li.selected {
  background-color: #f8d0d8;
  }
```

to check the current selected element during any over.

For the JS side, do not neglect the particularities of the method  [`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)
1- it returns a boolean value
2- it allows optionally to force or not the assignment of a class

full code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul#vertical-accordion > li').forEach( (li,_,all) =>
  {
  li.onclick =_=>
    {
    if (li.classList.toggle('selected'))
      {
      all.forEach( aLi => aLi.classList.toggle('selected',aLi===li));
      }
    }  
  });
```

```css
body {
  width  : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  margin : 0;
  }
ul,
li {
  margin     : 0;
  padding    : 0;
  list-style : none;
  }
ul {
  display  : flex;
  overflow : hidden;
  height   : 100vh;
  width    : 100vw;
  }
li {
  overflow-y         : scroll;
  overflow           : auto;
  -webkit-box-flex   : 1;
  -webkit-flex       : 1;
  -ms-flex           : 1;
  flex               : 1;
  width              : 8.3vw;
  height             : calc(100% - 1%);
  -webkit-transition : -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition : -webkit-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : -ms-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : flex 500ms ease-out;
  padding            : 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  -moz-box-shadow    : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  box-shadow         : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  }

ul#vertical-accordion:not(:hover) li.selected,
li:hover {
  -webkit-box-flex : 30vw;
  -webkit-flex     : 30vw;
  -ms-flex         : 30vw;
  flex             : 30vw;
  }
ul#vertical-accordion:hover li.selected {
  background-color: #f8d0d8;
  }
.projects {
  width         : 30vw;
  height        : auto;
  margin-bottom : 5vh;
  }

/* ------- PARAGRAPH STYLES ------- */

a {
  text-decoration : none;
  color           : black;
  }
a:hover {
  opacity : 0.5;
  }
.maintitle {
  width          : 100%;
  font-size      : 30px;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  font-family    : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
.subtitle {
  width       : 150vw;
  font-size   : 20px;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
/* ---removed for this sample  
img {
  padding-top : 20px;
  width       : 25vh;
  height      : auto;
  }
*/
```

```html
<ul id="vertical-accordion">
  <!-- MICRO-1-->
  <li>
    <div class="projects ">
      <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
        <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
        <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
        <!-- img src="gif5.gif " -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?random=1">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="projects ">
      <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
        <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
        <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
        <!-- img src="gif5.gif " -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?random=2">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="projects ">
      <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
        <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
        <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
        <!-- img src="gif5.gif " -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?random=3">
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <!-- PROJECT 2-->

  <li>
    <div class="projects ">
      <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
        <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
        <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
        <!-- img src="gif5.gif " -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?random=4">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="projects ">
      <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
        <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
        <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
        <!-- img src="gif5.gif " -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?random=5">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="projects ">
      <a href="matilde/matilde.html ">
        <div class="maintitle "> Networked Infrastructures</div>
        <div class="subtitle "> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
        <!-- img src="gif5.gif " -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100?random=6">
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <!-- PROJECT 3 -->

  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```